# Bind to AngularJS Service property

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I have a web page which uses a custom service to manage a map on the View (OpenLayers). I want to be able to display information about different markers on the page somewhere which means binding to a service property. The service is being called from a custom directive, and the binding (as far as I know) should be done from the Controller. The data being shown at the moment is the initialised object rather than binding to any changes to that object.

**`main.html`**

```
<h2>My Map</h2>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<p>
    Name: {{selected.name}}</br>
    Routers: {{selected.routers}}</br>
    Switches: {{selected.switches}}
</p>
```

**`main.ctrl.js`**

```
angular.module("app").controller("MainController", function($scope, openlayers){
    openlayers.init();
    $scope.selected = openlayers.selected;
});
```

**`openlayers.js`**

```
angular.module("app").factory("openlayers", function(){

    var init = function(){
        var vectorLayers = [new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
        })];
        vectorLayers.push(createMapLayer("red"));
        vectorLayers.push(createMapLayer("orange"));
        vectorLayers.push(createMapLayer("blue"));

        setUpMap(vectorLayers);
    };

    var activeVector = {
            name: null,
            routers: null,
            switches: null
    };

    function createMapLayer(markerColor){
        var vectorSource = getVectorSource();

        //add the feature vector to the layer vector, and apply a style to whole layer
        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: getVectorSource(cities[markerColor]),
          style: getIconStyle(markerColor)
        });

        return vectorLayer;
    }

    function getVectorSource(cities){

        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
              //create empty vector
            });

        //create a bunch of icons and add to source vector
        for (var index in cities){
            var city = cities[index];

            var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new  ol.geom.Point(
                    ol.proj.transform(
                            [city.lon, city.lat], 
                            'EPSG:4326',   
                            'EPSG:3857'
                )),
                name: city.name,
                routers: 200,
                switches: 100
            });

            vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
        }

        return vectorSource;
    }

    function getIconStyle(markerColor){

        //create the style
        return new ol.style.Style({
          image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
            anchor: [0.5, 46],
            anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
            anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
            opacity: 0.75,
            src: "Images/"+markerColor+"-marker.png"
          }))
        });
    }

    function setUpMap(vectorLayers){

        var map = new ol.Map({
           target: 'map',
           layers: vectorLayers,
           view: new ol.View({
             center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([2.808981, 46.609599]),
             zoom: 4
           })
         });

        addClickEventsToMapItems(map);

    }

    function addClickEventsToMapItems(map){

        var interaction = new ol.interaction.Select({
            condition: ol.events.condition.click
        });

        map.addInteraction(interaction);

        interaction.on("select", function(e){
            activeVector.name = e.target.getFeatures().item(0).get("name");
            activeVector.routers = e.target.getFeatures().item(0).get("routers");
            activeVector.switches = e.target.getFeatures().item(0).get("switches");
        });
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        selected: activeVector
    };

});

var red_cities = [
            { "lat": 40.462663, "lon": -3.626368, "name": "madrid" },
            { "lat": 53.381129, "lon": -1.470085, "name": "sheffield" },
            { "lat": 48.856614, "lon": 2.352222, "name": "paris" }
        ];

var orange_cities = [
            { "lat": 53.480759, "lon": -2.242631, "name": "manchester" },
            { "lat": 53.551085, "lon": 9.993682, "name": "hamburg" },
            { "lat": 50.850340, "lon": 4.351710, "name": "brussels" }
        ];

var blue_cities = [
            { "lat": 43.552847, "lon": 7.017369, "name": "cannes" },
            { "lat": 51.507351, "lon": -0.127758, "name": "london" },
            { "lat": 52.370216, "lon": 4.895168, "name": "amsterdam" },
            { "lat": 36.140751, "lon": -5.353585, "name": "gibraltar" }
        ];

var cities = {
        red: red_cities,
        orange: orange_cities,
        blue: blue_cities
};
```

EDIT: Removed the directive to simplify the code.

Comment: If your directive is calling "manipulateActiveVector" then you should see "selected.name" change from "<empty>" to "test". You can see a simplification of your code here http://plnkr.co/edit/qpXEA3jkmWxK3uTxKipB

Comment: The value has to be changed from within the service because it is called whenever a user clicks on a marker which is on the map. The event is caught in the service and appropriate changes are made. There must be a way I can bind it

Comment: Yes, understand. The plunkr I linked above is a similar code, except that the service function is called from the controller to simplify the example. You shouldn't have any problem as you are "binding" the "selected" service object to your controller scope and it should react to changes and display the changed value. Your angularjs code is fundamentally correct. What problem are you having? Can the problem be for something completely different and related to some code you haven't shown here?

Comment: The problem is that when the value is changed (which does happen - I checked using `console.log()` inside the service) the change is not reflected on the view. I will update the post with the entire service file and the structure of my solution.

Comment: I saw the updated code. In the directive... do you replace the "selected" object or you change the "name" property value only? I modified the plunkr to illustrate this detail: http://plnkr.co/edit/qpXEA3jkmWxK3uTxKipB and show the difference